# How to perfectly sync (< 30ms) two html audio element?

Tags: html, synchronization, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to perfectly sync two audio. Even if I launch them at the same time, they are desynchronized and the offset between them is varying. (I really can't understand how the offset can varying)

Here is a fiddle to show that desync.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vL4puo3/)

```
let bgMusic = document.getElementById('bgMusic')
let song = document.getElementById('song')
let interval;

let context = new AudioContext()
let destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination()
let localDest = context.createMediaStreamDestination()
let source = context.createMediaElementSource(song)
source.connect(destination)
source.connect(localDest)
let localStream = window.URL.createObjectURL(localDest.stream)
bgMusic.setAttribute('src', localStream)

let playButton = document.getElementById('play')
let stopButton = document.getElementById('stop')

playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    bgMusic.play()  
  song.play()
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('offset', song.currentTime - bgMusic.currentTime)
  }, 1000)
})

stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    bgMusic.pause()
  song.pause()
```

Do you have any solution to sync them even if I have to use only the web audio API ?

Comment: The JSfiddle doesn't work anymore. Can you provide an updated sample? Or if you've solved tell us how you did it?